# Animated UserControl : StoryBoard not starting?

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, storyboard

I'm trying to create an animation in one of my apps.

The animation is a Control that has a StoryBoard defined in its Resources and starts this StoryBoard after it's been loaded. Here's the (somewhat stripped) XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LernInsel.Resources.Assets.Water" x:Name="UserControl">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="BaseAnimation" x:Name="BaseAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveLeft">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="0.45"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.3" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveRight">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="0.45"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.3" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveLeft_Copy">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.39"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveRight_Copy">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.39"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveLeft_Copy1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.41"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveRight_Copy1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.41"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveLeft_Copy2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.9" Value="0.35"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.9" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="waveRight_Copy2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.9" Value="0.35"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.9" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
  </UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BaseAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
  <Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="#FF0B5FBC" Height="88" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveLeft" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="25.5,6,286.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveRight" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="308.5,6,3.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveLeft_Copy" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="-3.5,15,315.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveRight_Copy" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="279.5,15,32.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveLeft_Copy1" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="45.5,25,266.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveRight_Copy1" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="0,25,-16.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveLeft_Copy2" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="-3.5,38,315.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="waveRight_Copy2" Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=waveBright}" Height="60" Margin="279.5,38,32.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I create an instance of this on my Window, this looks fine in the designer, even the animation is being displayed. At Runtime, the Control is displayed as a unicolor Box (background color), but the animation never starts. Do you see anything wrong with the way Blend created the Trigger that might keep it from working?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Sebi

Comment: I don't see any key frames...

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant by stripped...I'll update the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reproduce this, given that `waveBright` is actually defined in a reachable scope of your `UserControl`. This might be the only weakness of that code.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the case. Sometimes you just run into the most stupid of traps...